# Access methods from custom User class trough the Auth class

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I use Laravel 5 and the Modules package (http://codex.caffeinated.ninja/modules/master) to make a user system. I have created a User class with a method to check if a user has a specific role.

How do I access that method for the current user?

I have tried to use `Auth::user()->user_role('min', 'admin')`, but get this error:

```
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::user_role()
```

I have created my own AuthController, which is working fine.

I don't know if it is because the Auth class not use my custom User class, because I have not defined that anywhere except in my AuthController? And if so, how do I change that? Or should I do it differently, is there a better method to accomplish this?

Comment: So you cant simply use and extend the default Authenticatable trait?

Comment: As i said, I have no problem with my custom AuthController. The problem is, that the Auth class that I access the current user from (Auth::user()) is using the standard User class bundled with Laravel 5 (App/User). But because I use the Modules package, my custom User class is stored in (App/Modules/UserSystem/User), and I need the Auth class to take my custom user class instead of the standard userclass

Comment: Change the user model being used within the config if you want to use your version then. This can be found in `config/auth.php`.

Comment: Thank You, you just saved my day :) I will look in the config files next time I have to change a configuration :)

Comment: I shall add as an answer for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the default `Auth` user model being used within the config. This can be found in `config/auth.php`.